# CultureInfo : display the language with its own culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

The title may not be very clear but what I want to do is really simple: I want to display a list of culture by their names like this:

- English for culture "en"
- Deutsch for culture "de"
- Français for culture "fr
- Italiano for culture "it"
- Español for culture "es"
- etc...

Comment: what language are you coding in? how do you want to output the data on a webpage or csv? Have you tried any code yet? How far did you get, what error messages or issues did you come across?

Comment: Consider CultureInfo.NativeName.  Beware of displaying text in non-Latin alphabets.  Rough on console apps, rough on users that can't read text in such an alphabet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will display the name in the required (native) language:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en").NativeName);
Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de").NativeName);
Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr").NativeName);
```

Comment: This is the right answer.
NativeName display the culture in the culture language.
DisplayName display the culture in the machine local culture

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

See [CultureInfo.NativeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.nativename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
CultureInfo myCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("es", false);
Console.Write(myCultureInfo.NativeName);
```

**EDIT:** changed `DisplayName` method to `NativeName` as I realized the OP asked for it.

Comment: DisplayName is in the current culture, what I was looking for is NativeName

Answer (score 0):

The below little code snippet will get all the available culture and print it in tabular format. The output of the code is given below,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        CultureInfo[] cinfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);

        Response.Write("<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Country Name</th><th>Language-Country code</th></tr>");

        foreach (CultureInfo cul in cinfo)

        {

            Response.Write("<tr>");

            Response.Write("<td>" + cul.DisplayName + " </td><td> " + cul.Name + "</td>");

            Response.Write("</tr>");

        }

        Response.Write("</table>");

    }
```

Comment: DisplayName is in the current culture, what I was looking for is NativeName